# While using a bot, can I report on the time it takes between when a chasitor requests a transfer to a live agent to when the agent accepts the chat?

Tags: reporting, liveagent, chat

We use a Bot and then users can ask to transfer to a live Agent (we use live agent still). Leadership wants to report on the time it takes from the chat transfer request to an agent to the time the agent responds in order to gauge the effectiveness of adding the functionality for requestors to wait in additional chat queue space.

The only way I can figure to do it is to use the chat events object and loop through them and pull the times from each event, per chat transcript Id.  This seems like a cumbersome way to do it.  Is there another way? (without exporting the data into database and using SQL etc.? We don't have tableau connected).